# PGFPlots making small logarithmic values presentable

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

My data is really not clearly visible, as in: no error whiskers can be seen for `50x150-k1` nor `50x150-k1`. This is (obviously) because these values are really small, compared to `40x150-k`. I thought i could make the x axis logarithmic (as in the example below), but this didn't help out much. I Expect the error wiskers of `50x150-k2` be (visibly) almost as big as `16x75-s`, since they have similar kdelta value.

Whiskers are given by k-1 and k+1 according to table, with kdelta being k+1 / k-1.

[image: Example]

My code producing the graph in the image looks like:

```
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\data
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/error/.style={
    create col/expr={\thisrow{uci}-\thisrow{mean}}
  }
}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[y=-\baselineskip,
        scale only axis,
        width             = 7cm,
        enlarge y limits  = {abs=0.5},
        axis y line*      = middle,
        y axis line style = dashed,
        ytick             = \empty,
        axis x line*      = bottom,
        xmode=log,
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,x dir=both, x explicit]
        table [x=mean,y expr=\coordindex,x error=error]{\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What code would present the error margins better? I'm still expecting log10 to be the correct.

Full code and data:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{stix}           % font

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    output-exponent-marker = \ensuremath{\mathrm{e}},
    exponent-product={},
    retain-explicit-plus
}

% Read data file, create new column ``upper CI boundary - mean''
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\data
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/error/.style={
    create col/expr={\thisrow{uci}-\thisrow{mean}}
  }
}

% Define the command for the plot
\newcommand{\errplot}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[y=-\baselineskip,
        scale only axis,
        width             = 7cm,
        enlarge y limits  = {abs=0.5},
        axis y line*      = middle,
        y axis line style = dashed,
        ytick             = \empty,
        axis x line*      = bottom,
        xmode=log,
      ]
      % ``mean'' must be present in the datafile,
      %``error'' is the newly generated column
      \addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,x dir=both, x explicit]
        table [x=mean,y expr=\coordindex,x error=error]{\data};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
% Get number of rows in datafile


\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\data}
\let\numberofrows=\pgfplotsretval

% Print the table
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={name,error,mean,lci, uci, frac},
  % Booktabs rules
  every head row/.style={
        before row={%
            \toprule
            & \textbf{Felmarginaler} $\log_{10}$& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Värden för \mu_i \pm 1\%}} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
        },
        after row={ \midrule},
   },
  every last row/.style = {after row=[3ex]\bottomrule},
  % Set header name
  columns/name/.style = {string type, column name=\textbf{ID}},
  % Use the ``error'' column to call the \errplot command in a multirow cell
  % in the first row, keep empty for all other rows
  columns/error/.style = {
    column name = {},
    assign cell content/.code = {% use \multirow for Z column:
    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
    {\multirow{\numberofrows}{6.5cm}{\errplot}}%
    \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
    \fi
    }
  },

  columns/mean/.style = {
    column name = $k$,
    string type,
    column type={S},
  },
  columns/lci/.style = {
    column name = $k_{-1}$,
    string type,
    column type={c},
  },
  columns/uci/.style = {
    column name = $k_{+1}$,
    string type,
    column type={c},
  },
  columns/frac/.style = {
    column name = $k_{\Delta}$,
    string type,
  },
]{\data}
\end{document}
```

In data.txt:

```
name mean lci uci frac
16x75-s-k      1.18e-3 9.85e-4 1.50e-3 152\%
40x150-k       3.07e-4 1.76e-4 4.37e-4 248\%
50x150-k$_{1}$ 6.45e-4 5.76e-4 6.50e-4 112\%
50x150-k$_{2}$ 5.94e-5 4.71e-5 6.00e-5 127\%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```
x error plus=uci,x error minus=lci
```

to get going

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{stix}           % font

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    output-exponent-marker = \ensuremath{\mathrm{e}},
    exponent-product={},
    retain-explicit-plus
}

% Read data file, create new column ``upper CI boundary - mean''
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\data
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/error/.style={
    create col/expr={\thisrow{uci}-\thisrow{mean}}
  }
}

% Define the command for the plot
\newcommand{\errplot}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[y=-\baselineskip,
        scale only axis,
        width             = 7cm,
        enlarge y limits  = {abs=0.5},
        axis y line*      = middle,
        y axis line style = dashed,
        ytick             = \empty,
        axis x line*      = bottom,
        xmode=log,
      ]
      % ``mean'' must be present in the datafile,
      %``error'' is the newly generated column
      \addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,x dir=both, x explicit]
        table [x=mean,y expr=\coordindex,
            x error plus=uci,x error minus=lci]{\data};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
% Get number of rows in datafile

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\data}
\let\numberofrows=\pgfplotsretval

% Print the table
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={name,error,mean,lci, uci, frac},
  % Booktabs rules
  every head row/.style={
        before row={%
            \toprule
            & \textbf{Felmarginaler} $\log_{10}$& &
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{V\"arden f\"or $\mu_i \pm 1\%$}} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
        },
        after row={ \midrule},
   },
  every last row/.style = {after row=[3ex]\bottomrule},
  % Set header name
  columns/name/.style = {string type, column name=\textbf{ID}},
  % Use the ``error'' column to call the \errplot command in a multirow cell
  % in the first row, keep empty for all other rows
  columns/error/.style = {
    column name = {},
    assign cell content/.code = {% use \multirow for Z column:
    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
    {\multirow{\numberofrows}{6.5cm}{\errplot}}%
    \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
    \fi
    }
  },
  columns/mean/.style = {
    column name = $k$,
    string type,
    column type={S},
  },
  columns/lci/.style = {
    column name = $k_{-1}$,
    string type,
    column type={c},
  },
  columns/uci/.style = {
    column name = $k_{+1}$,
    string type,
    column type={c},
  },
  columns/frac/.style = {
    column name = $k_{\Delta}$,
    string type,
  },
]{\data}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I focused on the main point and added two `$` to make the code compile. One could further tune the code.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Works correctly, unsure what the 'error' argument is to be used for. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @Olle You are welcome! I think the logarithmic plots are a bit special because one cannot simply add errors because `log(x+y)` is not equal to `log(x)+log(y)`. Therefore it must be "known" at which point the error bar is to be attached.